# Terraform is adding/removing same resource

Tags: terraform

I have this definition for a CloudFront origin that isn't modified but one other Origin and Origin Group is added.  However when I do a plan I see that Terraform is removing and adding back the exact same thing to the definition that isn't being modified.  Is this being triggered by some inconsistency in my template or is this just what Terraform decides to do based on it's algorithm?  Effectively, the block below does basically nothing.

```
  - origin {
      - domain_name = "dev-uis-e1.s3.amazonaws.com" -> null
      - origin_id   = "S3-dev-uis-e1" -> null

      - s3_origin_config {
          - origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/NNN" -> null
        }
    }
  + origin {
      + domain_name = "dev-uis-e1.s3.amazonaws.com"
      + origin_id   = "S3-dev-uis-e1"

      + s3_origin_config {
          + origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/NNN"
        }
    }
  - origin {
      - domain_name = "dev-uis.s3.amazonaws.com" -> null
      - origin_id   = "S3-dev-uis" -> null

      - s3_origin_config {
          - origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/NNN" -> null
        }
    }
  + origin {
      + domain_name = "dev-uis.s3.amazonaws.com"
      + origin_id   = "S3-dev-uis"

      + s3_origin_config {
          + origin_access_identity = "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/NNN"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your Terraform code look like? Can you please post it ideally as a [mcve] that when repeatedly run shows the repeated diff?

Comment: thanks, I managed to find the solution to the problem, I posted it here

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has an issue with it, I stumbled upon the solution to this issue here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12065

Apparently Terraform was detecting a NULL value vs an Empty string "" for the `origin_path` property.  Setting it explicitly to `origin_path = ""` fixed the issue.